How to seal indoor rendering?
I'm working on making my chimney hearth nice.  But before and after plastering, it appears that there is moisture coming through on part of the rendering.  I realise I can't go further until this is fixed.
Assuming my roof being redone soon will fix the moisture source, how can I seal over the rendering as well to prevent it from affecting the plaster?
You can see in the photo the stained section in the middle of the rendering is where there is moisture.

